# Showing there exist two points on line XY such that distance to two other lines is equal

Tags: geometry

Question

> $AB$ and $CD$ are two straight lines intersecting at $O$, Show that, in general two points can be found on line XY such The point is equidistant to $AB$ and $CD$. Also find the condition for which only one such point exists.

Clearly $AB$ and $CD$ are not parallel so in general, the three lines would form a triangle. This shows that atleast one point always exists (since inside the triangle the distances go from $(0,a)\to(b,0)$).

If $XY$ is parallel to any of the lines, then two such points.

How to proceed?

Comment: The problem seemingly has a few missing pieces. First, points A,B,C,D and O are introduced, then you need to find points on a line XY. What is XY?

Comment: If I understand your reasoning, you pick a point on line $XY$, measure the distance to the two lines $AB$ and $CD$, and deduce the existence of point(s) equidistant to $AB$/$CD$ based on how the distances change as you move along $XY$. To solve this problem formally, I suggest having a look at the set of (all) points that are equidistant to $AB$ and $CD$. On a side note, $XY$ being parallel to one of the lines is not the key property that decides whether there are 1 or 2 points.

Comment: @Ingix XY is another line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the points on line $XY$ that are equidistant from the given lines $AB$ and $CD$, these points must be in the geometric locus of all points equidistant from said lines which are the two bisector angles of these two lines.

Consequently, if the $XY$ line is not parallel to one of the lines $AB$ and $CD$ there are two equidistant points but if $XY$ is parallel to one of the bisector lines of these lines then there is just one equidistant point (lines $AB$ and $CD$ are supposed not parallels, of course).

Comment: Are you sure about the point that if XY parallel to one other line then only one point? I think the condition for just one point would bethe three lines being concurrent

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a lapsus and i wanted to say parallel to one of the two bisector lines (a way of say never touch one of these bisector lines).